# error: no match for ‘operator[]’?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdmap

I am trying to access the `std::map` data using `key`, but I am getting the error

> error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const std::pair’ and ‘int’)

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<map<int, double>> mainData;
    for(int i = 0; i  < 10; i++) {
        map<int, double> data;
        data[1] = i;
        data[2] = i*2.0;
        data[5] = i*7.2;
        mainData.push_back(data);
    }
    for(auto& it1: mainData) {
        for(auto& it2: it1) {
            cout << it2.first  << "    " << it2.second << "\n";
            cout << it2[5] << "\n"; // Error occurs here
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo here. I think you meant to access it1 instead of it2, because it1 is actually the map and it2 is the pair within the map.

```
cout << it1[5] << "\n";
```

Maybe you should use different variable names:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<map<int, double>> mainData;
    for(int i = 0; i  < 10; i++) {
        map<int, double> data;
        data[1] = i;
        data[2] = i*2.0;
        data[5] = i*7.2;
        mainData.push_back(data);
    }
    for(auto& map: mainData) {
        for(auto& pair: map) {
            cout << pair.first  << "    " << pair.second << "\n";
            cout << map[5] << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use `using namespace std` and then call the variables `pair` and `map`. You should not do this, because the names clash.

Comment: To clarify: this works, obviously. But a definition of a `std::map` variable using `map` in the scope of the first range-based `for`-loop will cause an unnecessary clash. It is in my opinion best to prevent this by not using the name of a type in namespace X as the variable name when using `using namespace X;` (or not using `using namespace X;` at all).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant to use `it1[5]`?

Answer (score 0):

it2 is a std::pair (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/). You meant it1[5] maybe ? Actually doing it2[x] can't work then there is a problem in the code you made

Answer (score 0):

because there are no [] operator for std pair, probably you mean it1[5] instead of it2[5]